# Visual Studio - Changed file name. Project now screwed up. How to revert to last build?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've been working on a small project and wanted to save it as "Main_V0.1". This has unfortunately screwed up a lot as you can guess. I'm still able to build the last successful build but I need to bring back the "Main" file to what it previously was. I can't find any helpful links. I still have all of my code but my Designer file is gone for "Main" too.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have backups? You may want to look at version control software in the future.

Comment: Use your version control software to revert. If you are not using version control software, create a time machine and send yourself back in time and tell yourself to use version control software.

Comment: Depends on what you renamed, in most cases these are fixable if you know where to look. We do not have any details on what you renamed. Did you renamed the solution? class? .sln project? Provide more information.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/HXRgl7f.png

The green highlighted ones are the okay files and the ones that are up in Visual Studio. The Red ones are the ones that came about after I tried renaming "Main" to "Main_V0.1"

Comment: Based on your image... Unless you know what file type they were previously rename their file type back to what it was. `.1` is not a valid file type VS recognizes

Comment: Exactly, which is why I'm so confused. I renamed my file but for some reason, Main.1 is what comes up in my solution on the right.

https://i.imgur.com/CJVIamF.png

Comment: My assumption is that `Main` should be a `.cs` type file system.

Comment: Figured it out. Had to delete "Main.1" in my project solution on the right then open the correct "Main.cs" and then go to View > Designer to bring it all back up. Almost had a heart attack.